# asp.net canvas control

Tags: asp.net, controls

is there any canvas control in asp.net ( not html5)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard canvas control in ASP.NET.

You can use GDI+ like this to create a dynamic image:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/gdiGraph.aspx

or you might want to consider using Silverlight or Flash in order to draw something.